# When changing the coordinates, waypoints are not created

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am using hardcoded coordinates to create waypoints on a map between two markers.

But it is working only for single coordinates. When I am changing the coordinates, it is not showing the new waypoints

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>Maps</title><style>
#map-canvas{
    height:700px;
    width:100%;
}
</style></head><body><div id= "map-canvas"></div><button id ="get">Get Directions</button><script>
function initMap(){
    var first1 = new google.maps.LatLng(27.721503,85.362072);
    var second1 = new google.maps.LatLng(27.711360,85.318781);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom:6,
        center: first1
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    function calculateRoute()
    {
        var request =
        {
            origin: first1,
            destination: second1,
            travelMode:'DRIVING'
        };
        directionsService.route(request,function(result,status) 
        {
            //console.log(result,status);

            if(status == "OK")
            {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
            }
        });
    }
   //  document.getElementById('get').onclick = function() {
        calculateRoute();
   //  }

}
</script><script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&callback=initMap"></script></body></html>
```

Expected: It should also work with the coordinates

```
var first1 = new google.maps.LatLng(18.496668, 73.941666);
var second1 = new google.maps.LatLng(18.550985, 73.934982);
```

Actual:
It is only working with the coordinates

```
var first1 = new google.maps.LatLng(27.721503,85.362072);
var second1 = new google.maps.LatLng(27.711360,85.318781);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to ask... How and where are you changing the coordinates in your code

Comment: @Samleo I think he just needs to use different pairs of coordinates in his code. The question title is misleading, it should be something like "Google maps does not accept certain coordinates".

Comment: Hmm so the issue is when the values in the code are changed from `(18.49.., 73.941...)` to `(27.721503, 85.362072)`?

Comment: @Samleo Yes, I think that's the problem

Comment: @user3543280 is there any specific error thrown? Is it possible that the coordinates are invalid or out-of-bounds or sth

Comment: @user3543280 I changed the "nodejs" tag to "google-maps" because your question has nothing to do with Node but with Google Maps

Comment: Sorry for misleading, I just want to use another pair of coordinates. Exactly David (y)

Comment: @Samleo , there is no specific error. It is just that the waypoints are not created.

Comment: @David, Please help here